# Cant find authentification details in new Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm a user of Magneto Enterprise 1.12.  We have the checkout hooked up to PayPal Express via the PayPal sandbox.  I dumped my cookies to fix an unrelated issue and on checkout I'm now redirected to the PayPal Sandbox. I only then realised that PayPal has now overhauled their Sandbox and my old auth details no longer work and the email address that I used to create the account is not recognised . YAY PayPal....great work!

I've since logged in with my Personal account (????) and have migrated the test sandbox accounts over, but I can only now get my hands on the REST API creds.  Magento requires the following for a test trans...

1. Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account
2. API Authentication Methods
3. API username
4. API password
5. API Signature

The new Sandbox site doesnt have links to this older API Cred info...only the rest API creds.

Has anyone found a link to this info?

Cheers

Luke

Answer (score 1):

In Applications > Sandbox accounts click on the email address associated with the test account and then click on the Profile link.

Answer (score 0):

i am in the same situation. did that but the old account does not have a signature anymore. however, there is a new account, created "by deafault" that does have a signature, yet when I try this account, the problem persists in so far as at the payment moment i am redirected to a sandbox page asking me to login to my sandbox account. Really strange!

Thanks anyway
Elliott